# Ordering of Locale.getAvailableLocales()

Tags: java, locale

Calling Locale.getAvailableLocales() lists locales in a certain order (eg:"en_US" is the first English language locale).

This works well for me but I was wondering:

Where is this ordering set? I tried to follow the source code but from the point where the raw data is retrieved: a `String` in a `HashMap`. Specifically: "[sun.text.resources.FormatData](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/util/LocaleDataMetaInfo.java#LocaleDataMetaInfo.getSupportedLocaleString%28java.lang.String%29)", to the point where the List is [returned](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Locale.java#Locale.getAvailableLocales%28%29), I cannot find where the ordering takes place.
(Notice that in the raw String data "en_US" is not the first English language locale).

Thank you.

Comment: Since the javadoc of the method doesn't provide any guarantee on the ordering you just shouldn't count on it. Sort the array yourself if you want them to be ordered.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the source code for [`Locale#getAvailableLocales`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/util/LocaleServiceProviderPool.java#LocaleServiceProviderPool.getAllAvailableLocales%28%29):

```
public static Locale[] getAvailableLocales() {
    return LocaleServiceProviderPool.getAllAvailableLocales();
}
```

And here is the source code for [`LocaleServiceProviderPool.getAllAvailableLocales`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/util/LocaleServiceProviderPool.java#LocaleServiceProviderPool.getAllAvailableLocales%28%29):

```
public synchronized Locale[] getAvailableLocales() {
    if (availableLocales == null) {
        availableLocales = new HashSet<Locale>(getJRELocales());
        if (hasProviders()) {
            availableLocales.addAll(getProviderLocales());
        }
    }
    Locale[] tmp = new Locale[availableLocales.size()];
    availableLocales.toArray(tmp);
    return tmp;
}
```

We can clearly see that the locales are being stored into a hash set, which has no ordering.  That the method ends up returning an array of locales is perhaps misleading as it might imply that there is some order.

As @JBNizet commented you would do best to just sort the list of locales in your own code.

Comment: Why misleading? Because a `HashSet` doesn't guarantee ordering but an array does? Nevertheless, the method returns locales in a consistent order (which happens to fit my needs). I wanted to see where the ordering is done to determine if I can rely on it but I see you and others suggesting that I shouldn't...

Comment: @theyuv And what happens when Java 9 introduces new locales?  Then the ordering breaks.